# transformar consulta de oracle a postgresql

Tags: postgresql

comunidad estoy intentando pasar una consulta de oracle a POSTGRESQL y no me ha funcionado como puedo hacerlo? el codigo es el siguiente:

Oracle:

```
create function updateinsert
create cursor xx
select id 
  from "CCRs"  
  where status = 'POR REGULARIZAR' 
    and id in (221424,188790);
begin
open cursor xx
loop

update ccrs 
set status  ='ANULADO', 
    isActive = false,
    cancelationDate = now(),
    updatedAt= now()
where id = xx.id;

INSERT INTO public.CCRHistories
(status, createdAt, updatedAt, ccrId, userId)
VALUES('ANULADO', now(), now(),xx.id , 2438);

end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que eso sería todo:

```
DO $$
declare
        registro record;

cur_id cursor for select id
from
    "CCRs"
where
    status = 'POR REGULARIZAR' and id in (204);
 begin
    open cur_id;

fetch cur_id
into
    registro;

while (found) loop

    update
    "CCRs"
set
    status = 'ANULADO',
    isActive = false,
    cancelationDate = now(),
    updatedAt = now()
where
    id = registro.id;

insert
    into
    CCRHistories
(status,
    createdAt,
    updatedAt,
    ccrId,
    userId)
values('ANULADO',
now(),
now(),
registro.id,
2438);

fetch cur_id
into
    registro;
end loop;
end $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```